# pinchgesture and two image zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, ios4

I have one image 768 x 1024 size.
second image is on that image at `x=50` and `y=100` with height of `30` and width of `1024`.

when i stretch first image second image stays as it is.

I want what ever part is hidden by second image to stay hidden as when i stretch image. 
basically when i zoom first image second image will also zoomed.

how can i do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if we want to zoom as this way add this two image on view and zoom that view.
Scalefactor at after zoom will as same as before zoom.**